# blue_thermal_printer is not working in 3inches bluetooth printer

Tags: flutter, dart, bluetooth-printing

[3inches printer error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwQjL.jpg)

I tried to print receipt in 3inches printer using all flutter print package.
Only blue_thermal_printer can print the output but the output is blur and there is three output.
The package is worked in 4inches printer. Other package also work in 4inches printer.
Is there any package that i can print in 3inches printer?
This is the printer i am using.[3inches Printer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Wi2W.jpg)